# Facebook Extended Permissions to access Non-Friends Album/Photo

Tags: facebook

Using an access token with offline_access (which I believe is the ultimate and most powerful extended permission), I can't seem to access a non-friend album (returns an empty JSON dataset).

However, using my Facebook account, I can view that album in my browser.

I've tried using friends_photos extended permission but I still can't view the album.

Is there a specific Extended Permission that I need to use or you're just not allowed to view non-friends albums?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't seem to access a non-friend
>   album (returns an empty JSON dataset).

Nope, that's not possible for privacy reasons. They should be your ***friends*** in the first place for you to be able to grab any information about them programatically. The extended permission `offline_access` won't help for any non-friend stuff.

Comment: That's a downer. I don't get the reason why this is disallowed. I mean, using any Facebook account then logging into Facebook, you can view this particular album. Why not allow it thru API?

Comment: @Ian: There is a difference in logging in and browsing website than using programming to get private data of others. You need to read facebook privacy for more info :)

Comment: @Ian - If I'm not mistaken, even if you're logged into FB, you can't view the album unless the user is sharing it at the level of your relationship (e.g. if they only share with friends and you're not a friend, you can't see it).  Which makes me wonder if those who share their photos with everyone *would* respond to your original request.